# Go from a variable type and define the corresponding largest available type, how do I do that in C++?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I currently have a template that makes some calculation, but there is a multiplication which currently overflows.

The input may be a signed integer, an unsigned integer, or a floating point number. What I'd like to do is cast the template parameters to the corresponding largest available type (i.e. int64_t, uint64_t, double) depending on the template parameter T.

```
template<typename T>
T scale(T value, T position, T count)
{
    return (value * position) / count;
}
```

When `T` is `int16_t` and a call such as:

```
int16_t result(scale(15'000, 3'000, 5'000));
```

returns an invalid number because the multiplication (15'000 * 3'000) is larger than what `T` can hold.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
    return (static_cast<largest<T>::type>(value)
                     * static_cast<largest<T>::tyoe>(position))
                                 / static_cast<largest<T>::type>(count);
```

where `largest<T>::type` returns the largest available type of the same signess for integers or `double` for floating points numbers.

Comment: Not `long double` for floating point types?

Comment: [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), [`std::is_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned), [`std::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed), [`std::is_floating_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point) . Simple enough to combine them together to create this. Possibly use [`[u]intmax_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) instead of `[u]int64_t`.

Comment: @aschepler In this case I won't need `long double` since the largest I use is `float`, but I guess that's a good point!

Comment: Also, you might consider `std::[u]intmax_t`, `std::[u]int_fast64_t`, `std::[u]int_least64_t`, instead of requiring exactly 64 bit types.

Comment: @Justin, Ah! Yes. I was thinking about `enable_if<>()` but could not see how to make it simple with such. The `std::conditional<>::type` is much better in this case.